# How to force trailing spaces in a right-aligned UITextView?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uikit, uitextview, text-alignment

I have a UITextView that can be either left-aligned, right-aligned or centered.
I noticed that if I right-align the textView, any trailing spaces in any of the lines of text in the textView are ignored. This doesn't happen for leading spaces when left-aligning.

Visually this is what happens (with '-' to visualize a space):

Left-aligned:

```
-some-text-
```

Same text right-aligned:

```
--some-text
```

Adding more text, brings back the trailing space in the correct position:

```
-some-text-b
```

I can't work out why this is or how I can force right-aligned text to present the trailing spaces on the right-hand side. Any suggestions?

Comment: I feel your pain. Got almost exactly the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53385139).