# NSTextField: do not strip trailing spaces while center-aligned

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

My crusade against static text `NSTextField` goes on.

The question for today is: Why do center-aligned `NSTextField`-s even dare to strip trailing spaces from the lines they are given? Why don`t they strip leading spaces then?

But, most importantly, how do I stop them from butchering my text?

P.S.: if you`re wondering why I want that, refer to this [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51643306/force-gtklabel-to-clip-its-center-aligned-text).

P.S.#2: seems like a similar question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23296012) — to no avail, though.

Comment: Well, the [docs for `NSTextAlignmentCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextalignment/nstextalignmentcenter) says that it's for **visually** centering the text. That explains the why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a quick experiment: Select the label field and in the attributes pane change the `Layout` from `Truncates` to `Scrolls` the text should now centre taking into account the trailing spaces.

Or you can start with an editable text field and turn off the border, draws background and editable behavior settings.

HTH

Comment: The first method worked! Digging a little further I found out that the actual property that does the trick is `NSTextFieldCell::scrollable`.